# How to unit test for the given code in Angular 8

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to execute unit testing for the below code

```
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
   this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
   this.DMDataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
   // console.log(this.dataSource.filter);
 }
```

Here is my Spec code for that

```
  it('apply filter', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'applyFilter');
    component.applyFilter('filterValue');
    expect(component.applyFilter);
  })
```

Still in the browser showing that code is highlighted in red, meaning it was not covered. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are spying on a function, whatever is inside is not executed and hence the content is not covered by a test. It's a bit hard to understand what you are trying to test. All your test is currently doing, is to test that your spyOn worked and the method was stubbed. You would need to stub you dataSource and DMDatasource and test that the filter was set instead of mocking the actual applyFilter method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test a method you need to check the results of its execution. By spying on it you prevent its execution. The better approach would be to execute the method and check the results.
It is also a good practice to have only one expectation inside one `it` block. Makes test more easy to maintain.

```
describe('applyFilter' ()=> {

   it('should set the dataSource filter to the provided argument' ()=> {
      component.applyFilter('filterValue');

      expect(this.dataSource.filter).toEqual('filterValue');
   })

   it('should set the dataSource filter to the provided argument' ()=> {
      component.applyFilter('filterValue');

      expect(this.DMDataSource.filter).toEqual('filterValue');
   })

  // test for trimming and lower case to here
})
```

Comment: thanks for immediate reply please let me know what I have with the cooments how to do the uppercase

Comment: I am getting one error TypeError: this.dataService.setBCNumber is not a function


this is the type script this.dataService.setBCNumber(null);